# Excel lookup to assign level based on Age and Weight

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a table of some 5,000 players with their age and weight.  I have a level table where I have created the max weight for each age and assigned a level.  The arrays in the lookup table are named 'Age', 'Weight', and 'Level" appropriately. The weight listed is the maximum for that age at that level, if the player's weight is over that they should go up to the next level. I have the lookup table below.  The player's age is in column E and their weight is in column K.

I need help with the lookup function that would assign the level to the player.

```
    Max   
Age Weight  Level
7   110     A
8   105     A
9   65      A
8   150     B
9   120     B
10  115     B
11  75      B
10  175     C
11  130     C
12  125     C
13  85      C
11  175     D
12  135     D
13  130     D
14  100     D
12  180     E
13  185     E
14  300     E
```

Not sure what you are looking at, my question is nothing like the referenced question.  The other question had a single variable, date, mine has two, age and weight.  The other question had sparse data in the lookup, mine is complete.

It is really poor form that someone can come by and downgrade your question without really even reading it.  They stated that my question was already answered and referenced something from two years ago that is not even related to what I am asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel: Lookup value in one table column and find the nearest value in another column that is sparsely populated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937776/excel-lookup-value-in-one-table-column-and-find-the-nearest-value-in-another-co)

Comment: It is ambiguous...........an 11 year old at 120 pounds can be either a **C** or a **D**

Comment: no, it is linear.  Since C comes before D if they fit in C they would go there, if they don't they go in D.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, I have re-structured your table as follows:

[image]

The order of rows in the new table does not affect how the formula works, but will allow you to verify that the formula is working correctly.  This should give the same assignments as your table, but allow a formula to look for a specific single row meeting the criteria.

I put an age in **F1** and a weight in **G1** and this lookup formula in **H1**:

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$19,SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$19=F1)*($C$2:$C$19>=G1)*($B$2:$B$19<=G1)*ROW($2:$19))-1)
```

This can be copied down
For example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a simple way of doing it, but the idea of this is that it tries to find a level that is within the player's age and weight. If that fails because the player is too heavy, it bumps the player up into the next level. That would mean that if the player is too heavy even for category E, it will put their category as F (my age and weight are in D2 and E2, the lookup table is in columns A, B and C).

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C$2:C$20,MATCH(1,(A$2:A$20=D2)*(B$2:B$20>=E2),0)),
CHAR(CODE(INDEX(C$2:C$20,MATCH(2,1/(A$2:A$20=D6))))+1))
```

It is an array formula and has to be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: It isn't working for me, this is what I got to:  =IFERROR(INDEX(level,MATCH(1,(age=E2)*(weight>=K2),0)),
CHAR(CODE(INDEX(level,MATCH(1000,1/(age=E2))))+1))

Comment: Yes this is basically what I get when I use named ranges =IFERROR(INDEX(Level,MATCH(1,(Age=D2)*(Weight>=E2),0)),
CHAR(CODE(INDEX(Level,MATCH(1000,1/(Age=D2))))+1)) where Age is $A$2:$A$20 etc. - make sure it appears with curly brackets round it. Is there an error message or just wrong answer?